# android studio master detail webview client stay in the webview

Tags: android, webview, client, master-detail

I am  making an app that you can open a website in a webview.
But when I try to go to an other webpage it tries to open a browser not in the webview.

Can you please help me.

original code :

```
((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_area)).loadUrl(mItem.url);
```

code with client thats not working :

```
 WebView webview;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webpage_detail,   container, false);

    if (mItem != null) {


        webview.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.detail_area);
        webview.loadUrl(mItem.url);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

    }

    return rootView;
}
public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please reply

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to go to an other webpage". Are you clicking a link, or calling webview.loadUrl(), or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.......

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(mItem.url);
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with some descriptive prose that explains what the code does.